# Scale-like ticks in Mathematica

Tags: plotting, code-request, ticks

I need to have axes ticks similar to the ones shown in the figure below but I can't find the command to do it. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: For the scale you can use `PlotRange` and for the ticks you can use `Ticks`. An example is the following: `Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 4}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.4}}, 
 Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1, 2}, Automatic}]`

Answer (score 3):

```
majorXTicks = 
 Table[{x, 
   Style[NumberForm[x, {3, 1}], Bold, "Arial", Black, 12], {0, 
    0.02}}, {x, 0, 2}]
minorXTicks = Table[{x, "", {0, 0.01}}, {x, 0, 2, 0.5}]
majorYTicks = 
 Table[{x, 
   Style[NumberForm[x, {3, 1}], Bold, "Arial", Black, 12], {0, 
    0.02}}, {x, 0, 0.4, 0.1}]
minorYTicks = Table[{x, "", {0, 0.01}}, {x, 0, 0.4, 0.05}]

Plot[0, {x, 0, 2}
 , PlotRange -> {{0, 2}, {0.0, 0.5}}
 , Ticks -> {Union[majorXTicks, minorXTicks], 
   Union[majorYTicks, minorYTicks]}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Comment: You are most welcome. You can experiment with the various tick options and make further improvements depending on usage.